# How can I command `zip -u ` to target folder?

Tags: zip, unzip

When I command  `zip -u hello.zip -f hello` it tells me to specify only one action!! I do not know how to fix that.

Comment: What is your OS? In Linux `zip -u` means "update", `zip -f` means "freshen". What do you want to do?

Comment: I thought -f was used to specify a destination folder, this is what I wanna do

Comment: My OS is Windows and also Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The
[zip manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip)
says :

```
-f
--freshen
    Replace (freshen) an existing entry in the zip archive only if it has been modified more recently than the version already in the zip archive; unlike the update option (-u) this will not add files that are not already in the zip archive.

-u
--update
    Replace (update) an existing entry in the zip archive only if it has been modified more recently than the version already in the zip archive.
```

The two options are contradictory - you should choose one of the two.